# javascript style all words between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to style some words in a string that contain special characters.
For instance If I have

`"I want to style words in single quotes 'blue' and brackets [red]. There are multiple 'blue' and [red] words in a string"`

I would like it to look like this without the special characters

`"I want to style words in single quotes <span class='blue'>blue</span> and brackets <span class='red'>red</span>..."`

How can I replace the end of the single quote with  in the method below?

This is what I have so far.

```
highlightMessage(message) {
    var text = message.replace(/[\[']+/g, "<span class='red'>")
    var text = message.replace(/]\]']+/g, "</span")
    var text = message.replace(/'/g, "<span class='blue'>")
    //how can I replace the end of the single quote with </span>
    //the method above replaces it with <span class='blue'>

    return message;
}
```

The other idea I have was to iterate through the string with `.split()` and check if the word ends with a single quote then replace that but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perform a single `replace` operation to achieve what you need:

```js
var s = "I want to style words in single quotes 'blue' and brackets [red]. There are multiple 'blue' and [red] words in a string";
var res = s.replace(/'([^']+)'|\[([^\][]+)]/g, "<span class='$1$2'>$1$2</span>")
console.log(res);
```

The pattern - [`'([^']+)'|\[([^\][]+)]`](https://regex101.com/r/1dM9ze/1) - matches `'...'` and `[...]` substrings and captures their contents, and replaced with the `span` tags using those contents as the attribute and node value.

**Pattern details**

- `'([^']+)'` - a single quote, then Group 1 (later referred to with `$1`) capturing 1+ chars other than `'`, and then a `'`
- `|`  - or
- `\[([^\][]+)]` - a `[` char, then Group 2 (later referred to with `$2`) capturing 1+ chars other than `[` and `]`, and then a `]`.

Since `$n` backreferences are always initialized with an empty string, there is no problem using `$1$2` in the replacement: only one of them contains text during each replacement, the other is empty.

Comment: Wow that was fast. You must type like 300 WPM cause I wrote about half as much in the same timespan +1